# Find optimum of function fitted with poly

Tags: r, optimization, curve-fitting, scatter, polynomials

I want to find the optimum of a function fitted through a scatter plot with `poly`.

Example data:

```
x <- c(32,64,96,118,126,144,152.5,158)  
y <- c(99.5,104.8,108.5,100,86,64,35.3,15)
```

I get the function with

```
poly(lm(y ~ poly(x, 3)))
```

But when I want to use `optimize`,

```
o <- optimize(f = lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)), interval=c(0,150))
```

I get

```
Error in (function (arg)  : could not find function "f"
```

How do I need to call optimize and possible helper functions to get the optimum (maximum in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Optimization: usually looking for a minimum

`Optimize` function states:

> The function optimize searches the interval from lower to upper for a minimum or maximum of the function f with respect to its first argument.

and

```
maximum logical. Should we maximize or minimize (the default)
```

So your formula would look for the minimum.

### Optimization of a function

`lm`does not return a function of x, it returns a list of elements (coefficients, intercepts, etc.), which you can use for your polynom.

What you need to do is to create a function `evaluate.polynom`

Which will return the value of P(x) knowing the coefficients returned by `lm`

## Edit: Checking results and caveats of `optimize`

### Result

```
X2<- x^2; X3<-x^3; df= data.frame(y = y, x = x, X2 = X2, X3 = X3)
L<-lm(y ~ X3 + X2 + x, data = df ) ### not being familiar with poly I prefer to do this
P<-function(x){ L$coefficients[1] + x^3 * L$coefficients[2] + x^2*L$coefficients[3] + x*L$coefficients[4] }
o<- optimize(f = P, interval = c(0,150), maximum = TRUE)
```

It says that maximum  is 92.

### Is it correct?

```
library(ggplot2);qplot(x = 0:150, y = P(0:150), geom = "line")+theme_bw()
```

[image: Polynom evaluation]

We can clearly see that our polynom reaches it maximal value on the edge, but there is a **local maximum that is found by `optimize`**. If you really want the maximum on your interval, I suggest evaluating your polynom on the edges of the interval too.

### Is the fit good?

[image: Comparison fit and points]

The fit we calculated with `lm` is correct, we did not make a mistake there.

Comment: so there is no built-in way to get the corresponding function, ok. And how can I access the coefficients of `lm`? Or should I take those of `poly`?

Comment: I added the code for how I would have done this. From what I understand in the `poly` documentation it already fits data. For example second row of `poly(x,3)` has negative values for first and second column (if it were x^2 it is impossible), and positive values for the third!

Comment: You should look at the edit. I don't know if you are looking for the maximal value achieved by the function on the interval or by the highest local maximum (edges of the interval are not local maxima).